# Build on appveyor .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: .net-standard, appveyor, .net-standard-2.0

I migrate my project (https://github.com/MarkKhromov/The-Log) to .NET Standard 2.0 and my appveyor build is broken. How I can fix this?

My solution contains:

- .NET Standard project
- Console Application project
- Class library (tests) project

I already tried wrote:

```
dotnet: 2.0.0
script:
  - dotnet restore
  - dotnet build
```

or

```
- dotnet build TheLog/TheLog.csproj -c Release -f netstandard2.0
- msbuild TheLog.Demos/TheLog.Demos.csproj /p:Configuration=Release
- msbuild TheLog.Tests/TheLog.Tests.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug
- nunit-console TheLog.Tests/TheLog.Tests.csproj
```

But every time I have errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your appveyor configuration to the VS 2017 image in order to build .NET Standard libraries and use the `dotnet` based tooling for `csproj` projects.

Comment: AppVeyor built-in `msbuild` based build phase works OK with  .NET Standard 2.0 projects on `Visual Studio 2017`. However, yes test execution should be done with `dotnet` based tooling.

Comment: I had a look at the build log from your latest commit on master and it was using msbuild 14 so I figured you hadn't selected the 2017 image yet. btw it doesn't matter if test execution is done via msbuild or `dotnet`, both call the `VSTest` msbuild target.

Answer (score 11):

Needed to change two settings on AppVeyor.
1. Change `Build worker image` to `Visual Studio 2017` - Environment setting
2. Add "*dotnet restore*" command into `Before build script` as `CMD` - Build setting

I've confirmed it on a new empty project/solution set on .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Core 2 .